# Regular expression to detect front-end language: i.e. CSS, JavaScript, or html?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a `<textarea>`. I'm trying to build a code beautifier. It should detect the CSS and HTML and JS scripts and It should Beautify. I'm already done with Detecting HTML using RegEx. Now, I want RegEx for CSS and JavaScript. Please Help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. Right now this is too broad/vague and is therefore off topic

Comment: this isn't a free code-writing service. better hire a freelancer instead.

Comment: try google for `regex for css` and `regex for javascript`

Comment: Thanks, I found for CSS. I didn't get that one for Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) and [Google Code Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify). Both of these have automatic language detection. And would be a good place to start to come up with a tried-and-true solution.

- Specifically, you may want to look at Highlight.js's [`highlightAuto` function](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/blob/master/src/highlight.js#L545).
- You can find the Regexes that GCP uses to detect [CSS here](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/src/lang-css.js), I couldn't find the ones for JS.